# Inline editing of website field deletes it

Tags: bug-reporting

When inline editing a website field, it deletes the field completely.

Inline adding a website does work, and it doesn't occur when editing the complete contact. I cannot find anybody else having this issue. Everybody can reproduce this on the demo site at:

https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=205

but it also occurs on my own 5.11.0 (In Drupal 7.65) site. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Steps to reproduce:

- open an existing contact with filled website field, or create one
- click on 'Add or edit website' next to the url
- edit the url and press Enter or click 'Save'

The website field is empty now.

Comment: Could you provide some more details on how one can replicate this error? If possible try attaching some screenshot or gif images.

Comment: just added steps to reproduce

Comment: Confirmed that it's a bug.  FYI, it's best to test on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org since that always runs the latest version.  The civihosting demo you linked to is out of date.  Could you create an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael,

Have logged an issue for this [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/842) and have also provided a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13929) for this issue. Can you please apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13929.patch) and test if it solves your problem? Also please try to comment on [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13929) if the patch works for you. This will fasten process of merging PR into core so that it can be available in next release.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Pradeep, thank you very much! This fixes the problem. I will comment on PR also, I am sure people will appreciate it if this gets into core :-)

Comment: So can you mark this as answered so that it will be help others in community